# i want use my angular 4 application as widget in other web sites - whatever websites language -

Tags: angular, widget, angular2-template

- i have an angular 4 application -using web-back -, i want insert my
  app as widget  in other web application/desktop without using i-frame tag, can I?

i have a way  but looking for smarter way

- i'm insert client js url tag in  other page
  and   tag in also.

but i think there are smart way to used my component.
notes 
i can update my angular version  if  this support me .

Comment: Are you asking about Angular Elements? (are like little component for the web, but it's Angular 6 or above)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to look into Angular Elements. Available starting on Angular 6. Basically it will package the application into a JS file, then you can just call the application using custom element like: `<super-power-widget></super-power-widget>`

For more info you can take a look at: https://angular.io/guide/elements